# Sum total Sales and Buys at same record group by month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which is like this.

```
id date       subtotal type
1 |2017-12-12 | 50.00 | 1
2 |2017-12-12 | 20.00 | 2
3 |2017-11-12 | 30.00 | 2
4 |2017-11-12 | 40.00 | 1
5 |2017-10-12 | 70.00 | 1
6 |2017-10-12 | 250.00| 2
```

In that case the type column presents sales (1) and buys(2). What I want to do is, group by this orders by month and get the total sale and buys at this month. Something like this.

```
id date        sale     buy
1 |December   | 50.00 | 20.00
2 |November   | 30.00 | 40.00
3 |October    | 70.00 | 250.00
```

When I try something like this,

```
 select to_char(date,'Mon') as Month,
       extract(year from date) as Year,
       case when type= 1 then sum("subtotal")  END as sales,
       case when type= 2 then sum("subtotal")  END as buys
   from table
   group by 1,2,type
```

result does not look like what I want. The months will appear at different columns. Like this.

```
month year    sales buys
Oct   |2017|  70.00 | 0
Oct   |2017|  0     | 250.00
```

How can I accomplish this? I just want to monthly sum records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select to_char(date,'Mon') as Month,
       extract(year from date) as Year,
       sum(case when type = 1 then subtotal else 0 end) as sales,
       sum(case when type = 2 then subtotal else 0 end) as buys
from table
group by Month, Year;
```

I often find it convenient to use `date_trunc()` in this situation:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as month_start,
       sum(case when type = 1 then subtotal else 0 end) as sales,
       sum(case when type = 2 then subtotal else 0 end) as buys
from table
group by month_start
order by month_start;
```

Comment: The first one works exactly like i want. Thank you. I dont get the second one thought. It gives only one value.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are grouping by year also, that's why its totaling everything in same row.
This should give you what you want:

```
select to_char(date,'Mon') as Month,
       extract(year from date) as Year,
       case when type= 1 then sum("subtotal")  END as sales,
       case when type= 2 then sum("subtotal")  END as buys
   from table
   group by 1
```

Comment: it says column "table.date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: My bad, you can include year column as well in group by clause, you just don't need the type.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
Select a.Month,a.Year,sum(a.sales) sales,sum(a.buys) buys 
from ( 
  select convert(char(3),date, 0) as Month,
         year(date) as Year,
         isnull(case when type= 1 then sum(subtotal)  END,0) as sales,
         isnull(case when type= 2 then sum(subtotal)  END,0) as buys    
   from _table    
   group by convert(char(3),date, 0),year(date),type
 ) a   
 group by a.Month,a.Year
```

Comment: I get syntax error on this one. Also i dont have a a.sales and a.buys at the beginning. I only have subtotal which i converted to sales and buys from type value.

Comment: There is no `convert()` in Postgres.